Object cache (cache layer for custom Store API route) lives few seconds on Shopware 6.5.8.10
I implemented an object cache (cache layer for custom Store API route) using this guide. After updating Shopware 6.4 to Shopware 6.5.8.10 my cache lives only about 15 sec (before it lives much longer I suppose a few days or even months).
This is debugging of the cache item when the cache is created firstly

and this is how it looks after ~15 sec

Additional info:

I use prod shop mode
I use default shopware and framework config for caching


The problem with the "Back in stock notifications" extension (version 1.7.14).  The extension runs every minute task calling "zeo_get_notified.stock_subscriber_notification_task" which cleans up the Shopware cache.
After deactivating the extension everything is OK.
